# Count the surface limited by two curves.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am not very familiar polar coordinate system and I am obliged to count surface limited by two curves $r=\frac{1}{\phi}$ and $r=\frac{1}{\sin\phi}$ and $\phi \in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ 
I know the formula for the surface $|D|=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^2(\phi)d\phi $.
I was thinking that I should find the points of intersection, but I couldnt find any. I will be glad for any help. I can not even imagine this two curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plotting these functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r%20=%201/sin%28theta%29%20and%20r%20=%201/theta%20for%20theta%20from%200.5%20to%20pi/2), you will notice that $r=\frac1{\sin\phi}$ is the line $y=1$. You can even verify this: $y=r\,\sin\phi=\frac1{\sin\phi}\sin\phi=1$. The other line is below this, although it converges to that straight line for small values of $\phi$.

Now your main problem is probably the fact that both areas are infinite, so taking the difference of the two integrals won't work. Instead, you have to move the difference into the integral:

$$\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\left(\left(\frac1{\sin\phi}\right)^2-\left(\frac1\phi\right)^2\right)\,\mathrm d\phi
= \frac1\pi$$

The result was [computed using Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/2%20%2a%20integral%20%28%281/sin%28phi%29%29%5E2%20-%20%281/phi%29%5E2%29%20d%20phi%20from%200%20to%20pi/2). I you have questions about how to do the integration here, please say so (in a comment to this answer or in an edit to your question which appends this), and perhaps some other answer to your question will include details on that as well. A useful step along the way might be knowing [the anti-derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/2%20%2a%20integral%20%28%281/sin%28phi%29%29%5E2%20-%20%281/phi%29%5E2%29%20d%20phi), since using that it is at least possible to verify that the result is correct.

Comment: Integration will not be a problem. How should I determine (without using wolfram alpha) whether I should substract one surface of curve from another ? Should I just solve this $\frac{1}{\sin \phi}\ge \frac{1}{\phi} $ ? Assuming I didnt come up with idea that $y=1$?

Comment: @MarcinMajewski: yes, after ruling out crossings, either consider the sign for one sample $\phi$, or simply do the computation in any order and take the absolute value in the end. If you have crossings, you might have to do absolute value for each interval if you really want area enclosed between the curves, but you already said (correctly) that there are no intersections here.